# When I activate a conda environment, username and current directory disappear in the terminal

Tags: linux, conda, slurm

I am working remotely on my university's cluster. I have created two new conda environments: `lammps-old` and `lammps-new`. When I activate any environmet of them the username and current directory indicator disappear. Now they also disappeared in the base environment.

I have tried cutomizing the `PS1` in the `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` using:

```
export PS1="($CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV) [$LOGNAME@$HOSTNAME($SLURM_STEP_NODELIST) $PWD]$ "
```

But this only solves the problem for the base environment.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing conda PS1 prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883992/changing-conda-ps1-prompt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `changeps1` to `False` by running the following command in the terminal:

```
conda config --set changeps1 False
```

or manually update `.condarc`.

https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#change-command-prompt-changeps1

Comment: do you know why is it happening?

Comment: The issue with setting changeps1 to false is that you won't see the currently activated environment as is the case by default.

Answer (score 3):

Run this command and try

```
conda init bash
```