# The username and current directory disappear in the terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, conda, miniconda, mobaxterm

After I installed sra-tools using conda, the username and current directory disappeared in the terminal. The situation did not change after I deleted sra-tools.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zza1V.png)

I have tried cutomizing the PS1 in the ~/.bashrc using:

```
export PS1="($CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV) [\u@\h \W]$ "
```

But this only solves the problem for the base environment.When I activate a new conda environment, the username and directory disappear again.

Then I have tried to set changeps1 to False by running the following command in the terminal:

```
conda config --set changeps1 False
```

But then I would not be able to see the environment I was in, whether in the base environment or otherwise.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be dealing with a conda 22.9.0 regression:

- see this StackOverflow question: [Changing conda PS1 prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73883992/5239932)
- see this GitHub issue: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11885

Comment: As suggested, the code "conda init bash" fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!